# create file on folder if not exists on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node.js-fs

I want to creat directory if not exist and then save the file that I got from Front-end

This is my code and it only does the part of creating folders, but my main problem is saving the file in this path

```
let directory = await './some-dir/'+d.getFullYear()+'/'+("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+'/'+(d.getDay().toString().padStart(2, "0"))+'/'+d.getHours()+'/'+d.getMinutes()+'/'+d.getSeconds()
    fs.mkdirSync(directory, { recursive: true })
```

Comment: what is the problem with saving the file in the path?
the  code you've give does create the directories.

i think you forget to post part of your code

Comment: [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) has [ensureDir](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/ensureDir.md).

Comment: Tangential, but a ~200-char line is... difficult to think about. And the spurious `await` is deceptive.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What's preventing the file from being saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to create a file in a folder (both of them do not exist), we can use this way.
Of course, in this example, the path of the file (folders) is first the number of the current year, then the number of the current month, and finally the current day
For the file name, the time of file creation is considered as the name
The value inside the file is also sent by the front-end `request.body.values[0]`

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

let d= new Date()
        const directory = await './some-dir/'+d.getFullYear()+'/'+("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+'/'+(d.getDay().toString().padStart(2, "0"))
        let name= (d.getHours() + '-' + d.getMinutes() + '-' + d.getSeconds()).toString()+".txt"
        fs.mkdirSync(directory, { recursive: true })
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(directory,name), request.body.values[0],"UTF8")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should help:

```
fs.access("./directory-name", function (error) {
    if (error) {
        let directory = './some-dir/' + d.getFullYear() + '/' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + (d.getDay().toString().padStart(2, "0")) + '/' + d.getHours() + '/' + d.getMinutes() + '/' + d.getSeconds()
        fs.mkdirSync(directory, { recursive: true })
    } else {
        // directory exists.
    }
})
```

Comment: From docs on code (internal): Using fsPromises.access() to check for the accessibility of a file before calling fsPromises.open() is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The `fs` library has [built-in support](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options) for making a directory only if it doesn't exist, so this can be done quite concisely. Also, it's not ideal to use the synchronous version `fs` library in an async function. Asychronoys code is more friendly to the javascript threading model (ie, it performs better).

```
const fs = require("fs/promises")

await fs.mkdir(directory, { recursive: true }) //  Calling fsPromises.mkdir() when path is a directory that exists results in a rejection only when recursive is false.
```